# SQL Profiler not showing the parameters passed to a SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, sql-server-profiler

I am a first time Sql Profiler user.I only want to check the parameters being passed from the SSRS report to SP it is calling.

So,I start the trace in SQL Profiler and then View the report during which the SP is called and the fields are populated.Yet,I dont see the parameters being passed to the report.

All I see in the Profiler is the SP:CacheMiss Event.

I dont know,if this matters but I would like to mention that the Profiler is being used on my Local machine whereas I am connecting the Application DB through VPN.

I set up the trace by giving DB username and password.One more thing I would like to mention is that I already have the application running,and at the point where the reports are being used before I even set up the trace,because as I understand trace takes up a lot of memory.

Am I doing something wrong?Please guide me.

**Also,the SQL server DB is SQL Server 2012, whereas the version of the SQL profiler is SQL Server 2008 one.Could this be an issue?**

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database server that the report is reading from? Which trace template are you using? I do this all the time.

Comment: Yes,I am confident that I am connecting to the correct database server.Well,the template shows only the blank option for me,so I am not using any I think.But in the events tab ,I have checked all the boxes for the  stored procedure.

Comment: Try using the starting and completed TSQL events instead, and remove your filter. Sometimes the filter works too well.